"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when running compiled javascript code with Node.js
I am using TypeScript to build a Node.js application. After compiling the code, when I run the output JavaScript file using npm start, it throws the following error:
When I run the following command:
npm start

I get this error:
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

My app.ts (mainfile):
import "reflect-metadata"

import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { useExpressServer } from 'routing-controllers';
import { connectDB } from './config/db';
import { CONNECTED_MESSAGE } from './common';
import { ENV_DETAILS } from './env';


dotenv.config();

// Create an instance of an Express app
const app = express();

// Configure built-in middleware to parse various types of request bodies
app.use(express.json()); // For parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // For parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded


// Configure routing-controllers with the Express app
useExpressServer(app, {
  controllers: ENV_DETAILS.dirs.controllers
});

// Connect to the database and start the server
const port =  3000;
connectDB().then(() => {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(CONNECTED_MESSAGE.listenPort, `${port}`);
  });
});

My package.json File:
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "tsx src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc && tsc-alias"
  },

My tsconfig.json File:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}

Environment : Node.js version: 20.12.2 and npm version: 6.14.11
I expect the command npm start to execute the compiled code without throwing an error.
Are there any issues with my configuration, or am I missing something critical?
How can I resolve this Error?

Add "type": "module" declaration to your package.json file and then ensure all modules that don't reside in the node_ modules directory (i.e. the ones you wrote) have their file extension added where you import them. So './config/db'; will become './config/db.js'; for example if that is what the file is called.

I am using 'type: module and I am checked node modules exist correctly. ' but it doesn't solve the issue?

Can you update your question then to show your code snippets in their updated state? That will help with debugging.

the config should be like: {
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "esnext",...
},
"tsc-alias": {
"resolveFullPaths": true,
"verbose": false
}
}
